# Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 310

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I planned to use Ubuntu for the first time (moving out of Windows 7) and started installing latest version through USB. During installation at configuring hardware, it stalled for 8 hours mentioning some warnings. I followed the process mentioned in the website for installation but still facing the issue.

I am using Lenovo Yoga 310 laptop.

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:133: Warning: Source Id 12573 was not found when attempting to remove it Glib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
```

The source id moved from 10,000 to more than 1 million but installation is not yet completed.

Comment: What kind of errors?  The more information you supply in your question, the better the answers it will attract.

Comment: Also what brand/model system? It took me 10 minutes to install to SSD, but about an hour and half to a slow flash drive (full install).

Comment: Pentium quad core processor

Comment: @RameshChandraChelikani, were you able to install ubuntu on your laptop? I'm trying to install ubuntu on my lenovo yoga 310 laptop also but I'm stuck with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was able to install Ubuntu and Zorin 12 in my Lenovo yoga 310. I went to the BIOS and enabled Legacy booting and made Legacy the priority. Inserted my bootable USB and installed Ubuntu.